# how to get application's original logo icon?

Tags: android, package-managers, graphical-logo

Application's icon can be gotten by following code:

```
Drawable drawable = ResolveInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
```

But it is the drawable that maybe modified by ROM (like: right-angle changed to round angle corner), so my question is how can I get original logo icon by program?

P.S.  some launcher can do this, like MIUI launcher.

Answer (score 3):

You can get application icon using `PackageManager`

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
Drawable appIcon = manager.getApplicationIcon(packagename);
```

Comment: it functions almost same as ResolveInfo.loadIcon(), NOT fit my requirement

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Drawable getApplicationIcon(Context context, String packname){
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        PackageInfo pInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(packname, 0);
        int resId = pInfo.applicationInfo.icon;
        AssetManager assetManager = AssetManager.class.newInstance();
        AssetManager.class.getMethod("addAssetPath", new Class[]{String.class}).invoke(assetManager, pInfo.applicationInfo.sourceDir);
        Resources oRes = context.getResources();
        Resources resources = new Resources(assetManager, oRes.getDisplayMetrics(), oRes.getConfiguration());
        Drawable result = resources.getDrawable(resId);
        assetManager.close();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return pm.getDefaultActivityIcon();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late reply. But I hope this will help someone new to android.

This method will get the icon associated with the Activity.

```
public static Drawable getOriginalActivityIcon(Context context,ResolveInfo resolveInfo){
    PackageManager packageManager=context.getPackageManager();
    try {
        ActivityInfo info=resolveInfo.activityInfo;
        Drawable drawable = packageManager.getDrawable(info.packageName,info.getIconResource(), packageManager.getApplicationInfo(info.packageName, 0));
        if(drawable==null){
            drawable=resolveInfo.loadIcon(packageManager);
        }
        return drawable;
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return packageManager.getDefaultActivityIcon();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packagename);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageInfo.packageName);
```

Comment: This answer is already provided by existing 6 years old answers.

Comment: you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The conclusion is that if a round icon exists and no adaptive icon exists, you can't get a square icon. Unless this system is customized with a different Android framework than AOSP, such as the MIUI.

At first I was just like you, looking around for a way to load the square icon. I've tried every answer including the ones here.
Finally I found that if both square and round icons are set, then the Android system framework returns the `ResId` of the round icon when you request the `ResId` of the icon. At last I went searching for [the code of the Android system framework](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/tools/aapt2/cmd/Link.cpp#1669) and verified this guess:

> When a developer specifies an adaptive application icon, and a non-adaptive round application icon, create an alias from the round icon to the regular icon for v26 APIs and up. We do this because certain devices prefer android:roundIcon over android:icon regardless of the API levels of the drawables set for either. This auto-aliasing behaviour allows an app to prefer the android:roundIcon on API 25 devices, and prefer the adaptive icon on API 26 devices.

If the application contains adaptive icons and the API level >= 26, you can use it to draw out square icon. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611448/how-do-launchers-change-the-shape-of-an-adaptive-icon-including-removal-of-back).