# How to find the current Icon Shape of apps?

Tags: android, package-managers, appicon, adaptive-icon

I currently load app icons clipped to their correct shapes using:

`context.packageManager.getApplicationIcon(packageName)`

But I'm looking into adapting a custom icon shape in my app based on user's app icon shape (Square, Teardrop, Squircle, etc) preference and I wonder if there's a way to find what the user's app icon shape preference is programmatically.

Comment: Launchers might allow users to specify a preference, but that would be up to the launcher. Not all launchers will offer this, and as a result I am not aware of any convention between launcher developers in terms of an API for outsiders to find out what the user's selection was.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611448/how-do-launchers-change-the-shape-of-an-adaptive-icon-including-removal-of-back

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [adaptive icons](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive). They do all that stuff for you.