# How do I get the legacy (non-adaptive) icon of an app programmatically?

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm making a launcher app, and I can't figure out how to get the pre-android8 icon of an app.
Is there a special function to get resources for a chosen API level?

Nova launcher is somehow able to get the old icons, but since it's closed source, I couldn't investigate its code.

[Here's a post asking the same question, which wasn't answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47611448/how-do-launchers-change-the-shape-of-an-adaptive-icon-including-removal-of-back)

Answer (score 0):

I found something. Though it doesn't behave like nova launcher & I only tested it on OxygenOS:

I used the `LauncherActivityInfo.getIcon(density: Int)`
function to get apps' icons. If you pass `context.resources.configuration.densityDpi`, it'll behave like a normal launcher, but if you pass zero, some apps will return a non-adaptive icon.